# Help with nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a way to explicitly solve the following nonlinear first order differential equation:

$$
\frac{\eta^\prime}{\eta}-\frac{3 \left(4 x^2+\eta^2+1\right)}{2 x \left(4 x^2+\eta^2-2-2 x\right)}=0,
$$
where $^\prime$ denotes differentiation with respect to $x$ and $\eta$ is a function of $x$ only. I strongly suspect a closed form solution exists, because its perturbative expansion at large $x$ is somehow simple, but I was not able to solve it for all $x$.

Comment: You should post since  *"its perturbative expansion at large $x$ is somehow simple"*. Moreover, tell us where the monster is coming from. Cheers :-)